# Can I force push into my branch and then merge into master?

Tags: git

I am developing some code on my branch, which later will go through the code review and merged into master. So all differences will be seen and validated before the merge.

If I apply force push on my branch and then merge the result it into master, would this force push have any effects on commits of other developers, made into master branch before the merge (not into mine)?

Comment: Yes you can, no it won't

Comment: ask yourself why you need force push first, force push will rewrite all remote commits, even it is only for your branch, it could also affect the master branch later, when you decide to merge it back to master, think through 3 times and make sure there is no other options, then use force push, and make sure you got the correct command

Comment: Since your branch may contain changes that affect others developers changes, merge may eventually reveal conflicts.

Comment: Yes, it's ok to force push on the branch but you need to do know it what you push it. But don't do that in master it's not encourageable. Even force push is not encourageable, if you're really aware that file changes your doing not introducing any regression then you can force push your branch and merge that in master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you force push from your local branch A to your remote branch A, that is

`local A --- force push ---> remote A`

Then you merge remote A to remote master through a pull request:

`remote A -- merge --> remote Master`

Then it wont have any undesired effect on other developers' commits.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the changes you are making since you are changing the history of the branch and could rearrange/revert other people's commits, but those changes will/should be visible on the pull request.

Here's a good article on force pushing and when you want to use it:
https://blog.sensible.io/2012/10/09/git-to-force-put-or-not-to-force-push.html